# Ethical factors to consider in case of a non-contributing co-author

Tags: phd, ethics, authorship, collaboration

I am a Ph.D. student. Currently, we are writing a paper. We can group the participants in the following way:

- Me and my collaborators who have done the majority of the work.
- My principal supervisor who helped me to access the lab.
- The person, let's call him Glideroy :-) , who is the subject of this question.

Glideroy has not made any substantial contribution. To be precise, he wrote one piece of code, which eventually was not used in the paper. Later we asked him for further investigation, which he didn't do.

One of our co-authors expressed his reluctance to include the non-contributing co-author's name in the paper. According to him, the decision is in the hand of the authors who have made a substantial contribution. My principal advisor is not aware of this yet, but he has a good relationship with Gilderoy.

Now I am in a tricky position, I agree with the non-contributing part. However, I feel a bit hesitant to burn the bridge and remove the author altogether. So, my questions are the following:

1. What are the criteria one should fulfill to be a co-author?
2. Should I talk to my principal supervisor?
3. Is there any way we can justify the inclusion of Glideroy's name?

Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: I think this question has been answered elsewhere on this site, perhaps search the forum for _authorship_

Comment: Can you clarify why Glideroy's code was not used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The criteria to be a co-author depend on the field of research and on the journal, but usually at least some intellectual contribution to the paper is expected. Most journals have a list of requirements on their website.
2. Yes, you should talk to your supervisor: this will probably solve the problem.
3. No, unless the code he wrote gave you important insights (even if the code was not used afterwards). But also see the answer to (1).

There are three possible outcomes:

- Your supervisor agrees to remove the co-author.
- Your supervisor convinces you that the contribution of the co-author was enough to earn authorship.
- Your supervisor wants to include the co-author for "political" reasons. This is wrong, but it happens quite a lot unfortunately. In this case it would probably be best to include the co-author anyway. It is wrong ethically, but if you and your co-authors did your best to prevent it that is on your supervisor and not on you: if you discussed it with him there is not much more you can do unless you want to risk the relationship with your advisor.

Comment: Item 3 is to some extent disputable: Even finding out that something doesn't work or help  can be an insight. Such a contribution could be classified as marginal, but it could still be used to justify inclusion.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my answer - that is exactly what I was trying to say. I have edited it to clarify.

Comment: You might be right. I guess I got confused because the answer defaults to "no" even though it seems more likely that the part after the "unless" is fulfilled.

Comment: I, too, find point 3 to be the important one. A "contribution" to the research can be fairly invisible in the final result and, yet, still in theory be essential.

Comment: My answer assumes that OP (and his co-author) have a good reason to doubt the inclusion of the "non-contributing" co-author. Of course it changes things if this is not the case. Indeed, point 3 is very relevant. I have added a third option to the answer to clarify this further.

Comment: +1 for point 3. When I'm doing research I often end up trying a bunch of options before settling for the best solution. They all take time and effort and contribute to the understanding of the problem, even those that didn't work (and didn't make it to the paper). If it was a collaboration and each co-author was in charge of trying out one of the candidate approaches, it would feel very unfair to disregard what everyone else did and only put on the paper the name of the guy who was trying out the winning solution.

Comment: Is point 3 recommending the OP do something unethical?

Comment: @Chipster Depending on your point of view: yes. The third outcome leads to the inclusion of an author who did not contribute enough to the paper to warrant this inclusion. Clearly this is wrong. Unfortunately this is the reality many scientists have to deal with, and if the first and second outcome do not happen, the third option is the best for OP. It would not have negative consequences for his/her career. Let's compare to buying food packaged in lots of plastic: not good for the environment so unethical by some standards, but if it is all that is available you do not have a choice.